# Couchbase v6.0 : Update Document content without resetting Document Expiration (TTL) value

Tags: .net, couchbase

I am using.Net Couchbase SDK(CouchbaseNetClient Package) to create a new document and while doing so I set the expiry value for the document. The expiry(TTL) value sets properly and works fine too.

Problem Statment- Once the document has been created, I need to update some of its content for which I am using N1QL. Here the problem arises, it resets the document expiry value to 0. Is there any way to not reset the document expiry while updating a document content.

Answer (score 4):

Any mutation with N1QL (UPDATE, INSERT, UPSERT, MERGE) will always set the expiration value to 0.

Setting the expiration through the N1QL is on the roadmap.

Answer (score 3):

As @vsr mentioned, you cannot currently maintain the TTL of a document via a N1QL DML statement.
The only way in 6.0 (and before) that you can insert a document with an expiration is via the SDK.

What you can do however, is to use N1QL as a method or retrieving the TTL if you want to manipulate it on the SDK level.

for example: `Select meta().expiration from bucket where meta().id = "xyz"`

Comment: I would like to add, that when using meta().expiration, this value should be covered by the index.
if you don't want to use covered index, use that query instead
1) Select meta().expiration from bucket use keys ["xyz"]
2) select meta().xattrs.`#$document`.exptime from bucket where meta().id = "xyz"