# N1Ql synatx sugar for update statement

Tags: couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

We know that n1ql comes with syntax sugar like :

```
#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} and fname = "abc".
```

How do we write a syntax sugar for update statement?

```
update student set lname="john" where userId="101";
```

I tried this but does not work

```
#{#n1ql.update} set lname="john" where #{#n1ql.filter} and fname = "smith"
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.repository.n1ql  . It look like nothing for update. May be you can try UPDATE #{#n1ql.bucket} set lname="john" where #{#n1ql.filter} and fname = "smith"

Comment: @vsr  can we set TTL at the filed level also?

Comment: N1QL doesn't have TTL support in DMLs. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59222862/couchbase-v6-0-update-document-content-without-resetting-document-expiration/59229610#59229610